# $\int _0^2\:\frac{2x-1}{\:x^2-3x+2}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

how am I able to solve this definite integral when it goes from 0 to 2; I know how to solve it for example

$\int _3^5\frac{2x-1}{x^2-3x+2}dx$

but not when limit is approaching from a negative number or a zero...

$\int _0^2\frac{2x-1}{x^2-3x+2}dx$

$\int _{-1}^2\:\frac{2x-1}{\:x^2-3x+2}dx$

Comment: Not possible. The integral is divergent (x=1 is a root of the denominator, split the integral at x=1 and you arrive at divergent integrals)

Comment: $$f(x)=\frac{2x-1}{x^2-3x+2}=\frac{3}{x-2}-\frac{1}{x-1}$$ has non-integrable singularities (simple poles) at $x=1$ and $x=2$. Besides that, the partial fraction decomposition provides a straightforward way to compute its antiderivative.

Comment: the roots of denominator are $1$ and $2$, so to be definite, the integration interval must not contain these values.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have that in $(0,2)$ the integral diverges, because in $2$ it behaves like the integral of $\frac 1 x$ (multiplied for a positive constant) in $0$ that is divergent.

Comment: ok say i have $\int _{-2}^2\:\frac{2x-1}{\:x^2-3x+2}dx$ ; here i can split the limit from -2 to -1 then 1to 2?

Comment: Bargagnati non mi rubare il lavoro! @TemurBakhriddinov: you may split what you like, but the integral over $(1,2)$ is still divergent.

Comment: Yes, you can, but generally if somewhere the integral diverges to $+\infty$ and in another point of the region where you are integrating it diverges to $-\infty$ you can't say anything about the integral in the whole region.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\frac{2x-1}{x^2-3x+2}=\frac{3}{x-2}-\frac{1}{x-1}$$ has non-integrable singularities (simple poles) at $x=1$ and $x=2$. Besides that, the partial fraction decomposition provides a straightforward way to compute its antiderivative.
 It also allows us to state

$$ PV\int_{0}^{2}\frac{(2x-1)\,dx}{x^2-3x+2} = PV\int_{0}^{2}\frac{3\,dx}{x-2}=-\infty,$$

$$ \int_{3}^{5}\frac{(2x-1)\,dx}{x^2-3x+2} = 3\log 3-\log 2.$$

Answer (score 0):

It is an improper integral, so you have to split it, for example like that:

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^2\frac{2x-1}{x^2-3x+2}dx&=
\int_0^2\frac{2x-1}{(x-2)(x-1)}dx\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{2x-1}{(x-2)(x-1)}dx+\int_1^{3/2}\frac{2x-1}{(x-2)(x-1)}dx
 +\int_{3/2}^2\frac{2x-1}{(x-2)(x-1)}dx\\
&=\lim_{b\to1^-}\int_0^b\frac{2x-1}{(x-2)(x-1)}dx
 +\lim_{a\to1^+}\int_a^{3/2}\frac{2x-1}{(x-2)(x-1)}dx\\
 &\qquad+\lim_{a\to1^+}\int_a^{3/2}\frac{2x-1}{(x-2)(x-1)}dx
 +\lim_{b\to2^-}\int_{3/2}^{b}\frac{2x-1}{(x-2)(x-1)}dx\\
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: how do you know where to split for partial fraction problems? I have a problem where i think it's already splitted:

Comment: $\int _{\frac{3}{2}}^3\:\frac{x-1}{x^2-3x+2}dx $ (how do you get it in the form of a fraction)

Comment: unless its 1, and 2; and 3/2 is 1.5 (sorry for making these multiple comments

Comment: Split as you like, as long as the point you choose is inside your domain